# Are Maurice Cole's eyes really as bad as they appear in "The Doctor, The Widow and the Wardrobe"?

Tags: doctor-who, actors

In the 2011 Doctor Who Christmas special [*The Doctor, The Widow and the Wardrobe,*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doctor,_the_Widow_and_the_Wardrobe) I noticed that the little boy is wearing glasses with rather powerful lenses (as opposed to "prop" glasses with plain glass). Was this just done for effect so his eyes would appear larger (which would make it pretty hard for the child actor to see what he was doing) or are Maurice Cole's eyes really that bad?

Answer (score 10):

It seems as though the actor's eyes really are that bad.

The character of Cyril Arwell was played by [Maurice Cole](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2910141/?ref_=tt_cl_t5). Other pictures of Cole show him wearing glasses that magnify his eyes significantly. The effect *appears* exaggerated in *Doctor Who*, but I suspect that's a property of the large, period-appropriate glasses; there's a distinct magnification in every picture I can find, even when he's wearing modern lenses.

For example, this picture from *The Times*:

[image: Maurice Cole and his enormous eyes]

Unfortunately, this seems to be the only information available. Other than a [short interview for the BBC regarding his *Doctor Who* character](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lj1wXeMPawo), there doesn't seem to be much in the way of interviews with him.

Comment: Also note those glasses look very modern, I assume the exaggerated ones looked more period appropriate for someone of his vision impairment

Comment: For the record, I did find an article about Cole in [*The Times*](http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/arts/tv-radio/article3587363.ece), but it's behind a paywall